# What's the difference between "hunt" and "hunt down"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrasal-verbs

The Google definitions are almost the same:

> **hunt**
>
> search determinedly for someone or something.
>
> **hunt down**
>
> to try to find a particular thing or person.

Example sentence:

> Pool parties were the perfect place for her: she could show off her
>   body, liquor up, and hunt (down) men.

Comment: In the sample sentence, "hunt down" is just a stronger image than "hunt."

Answer (score 5):

In general, "hunting" implies a high chance of failing to find, catch, or kill whatever/whomever is being hunted.

"Hunt down" implies persevering until whatever/whomever is being hunted is "caught" or "dead" (either literally or figuratively).  Often, this involves techniques to "corner" the target(s).  A target that has been "backed into a corner" can only escape by going toward the hunter(s).

"Hunt down" is also more likely to imply that particular targets have been identified.  For example, "hunt down men" might mean that:

- "she" has particular men in mind, or
- upon arriving at the party, she notices particular men, and will later on "hunt them down", or
- as men arrive at the party, she notices some of them, and will later on "hunt them down".

Comment: Yes, this exactly.  If she's "hunting" men it means she's "on the hunt", that she's just looking for an opportunity.  But if she's "hunting down" men it implies she's *determined* to get one before she goes home.