# What does "get" mean in "Whatever is out to get you, you’ve got to get it"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

What does "get" mean in the following quotation?

> Here’s what you’ve got to do with your worries: drive them into a small corner. Whatever is out to **get** you, you’ve got to **get** it. Whatever is pushing on you, you’ve got to push back.

Comment: Generally, if you're trying to define a word, we ask that you show what work you've done to find the answer yourself. I know that "get" has a lot of definitions but I know for certain that this definition should be in just about any dictionary. Please check a dictionary!

Comment: See also, "[What's the difference between 'hunt' and 'hunt down'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/114606)"

Answer (score 1):

I can see where this meaning of **get** might be difficult to find.

It means *to grab, to seize, to take hold of*, often with some nefarious intention.

> Young children who have nightmares are often afraid that a monster is
>   going to **get** them.
>
> I dropped my car keys down the storm drain. Do you have any kind of
>   magnetic tool that would help me to **get** them?

To be **out** to get someone means to be *trying* to get them; getting the person is your *goal* or *intention*.

So the advice in that passage is, "turn the tables, reverse the situation".  If something is trying to seize hold of you, don't act defensively; instead, go on the offensive, and go after it.